# How does Stabilization Window work with other scale down policies in Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, devops, amazon-eks

I was trying to understand Horizontal Pod Autoscaling from the documentation. The initial examples explaining usage of different attributes to configure the scaling behavior was clear.

However, this one [section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#default-behavior) called default behavior has an example showing a very counter-intuitive example for scale down configuration.

Here's just the scale down part of the scaling behavior:

```
behavior:
  scaleDown:
    stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
    policies:
    - type: Percent
      value: 100
      periodSeconds: 15
```

and here's their explanation:

> For scaling down the stabilization window is 300 seconds (or the value of the --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-stabilization flag if provided). There is only a single policy for scaling down which allows a 100% of the currently running replicas to be removed which means the scaling target can be scaled down to the minimum allowed replicas.

If I understand correctly [stabilization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#stabilization-window) essentially looks at the *previously computed desired states* from the immediate previous duration which is configured via the stabilization flag. In the meanwhile, the **policies** attribute right below **stabilization**, from the code block quoted above, describes a radically different behavior.

So I have some questions:

1. What exactly is the rolling maximum referred from under the **stabilization window** section of the documentation?This question stems from the following:

   a) From the given explanation in the docs, why does the desired state
   have to be inferred? Because isn't the desired state supposed to be
   a fixed threshold that the current state either subceeds or exceeds?

   b) Why would there be a need to average over anything other than the
   previous state (before the current state) or the previously income traffic?
2. How does stabilization exactly implement a rolling maximum over a period of 300 seconds if at the same time there's another policy which is to scaled down all the way to the *minimum allowed replicas* within a drastically shorter duration of 15 seconds?

I know my questions might reflect an incomplete understanding but please do help me getting the necessary intuition to work with HPA. Thanks!